# Invalid Label Error in JQuery when calling $.get function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Hi i am getting invalid label error nmy code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio Group Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/core.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      #result tt {
        color: maroon;
        font-size: 1.1em;
      }
      form>div {
        margin-top: 0.9em;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $.get('http://www.cloudspokes.com/challenges/1548.json', function(data) {
            alert(data); //uncomment this for debug

        },'jsonp');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='helloWorld'>Hello WOrld</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

i am new to jquery.search about this error but unable to resolve it.
when i call this url in my browser its giving me a json object http://www.cloudspokes.com/challenges/1548.json.
can any one please help how to resolve this error?

Comment: Does the API support jsonp? It has to in order to work. Also read up on jsonp on the jQuery site. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.